# ECDSA signing/verifiying appears to be only considering the first 32 bytes of the data

Tags: ruby, openssl, cryptography, ecdsa

```rb
ec = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new('secp256k1')
ec.generate_key
signature = ec.dsa_sign_asn1("A" * 64)
refute ec.dsa_verify_asn1("A" * 32, signature) # Fails here
```

Given the test code above, why `dsa_sign_asn1` and `dsa_verify_asn1` only considers the first 32 bytes of the provided data?

Environment:

Ruby 3.0, Ubuntu 21.04 running with multipass on Windows 10. `OpenSSL::VERSION` is 2.2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When signing, not the data itself is signed, but the hash of the data. This is necessary on the one hand to be able to sign longer messages and on the other hand for security reasons (s. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/6338)).

For secp256k1 typically a digest with an output size of 256 bit is used (s. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/19798)), e.g. SHA256.

If you take a digest with a larger output size, the leftmost n bits of the hash are considered according to NIST FIPS 186-4 (s. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/18489), where n is the key size, i.e. bit size of the generator order, 256 bit for secp256k1).

This is the reason why in the posted example the verification is successful: Only the first 32 bytes are considered, which are identical.

If the hashed value of the data is used instead, the verification fails as expected:

```
signature = ec.dsa_sign_asn1(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.digest("A" * 64))
verified = ec.dsa_verify_asn1(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.digest("A" * 32), signature) # false
```

Comment: Thank you for providing additional references. Before asking this question I did read some background. I learned that the data is hashed by a hash function at the first step of the signing, by the maths behind the ECDSA. However I'm not sure whether I should do the hashing, or the implementation hashes for me.

I also read the C code of ruby method `dsa_sign_asn1`, finding that it neither hashes nor cuts the message to sign.

Comment: Finally I tried with C code, doing the similar things. From which, I found that openssl's `ECDSA_sign` does cut the message to sign, retaining only the first 32 bytes. As per the references you provided, it works as intended.